# WebUtil's CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE when writing CSV files

Tags: oracle, migration, oracleforms, oraclereports

We're migrating our Oracle forms and Oracle reports from 6i to 10g over Windows 7. But when we changed the new PC's with Windows 7, users reported several reports and some forms that generates CSV files, they were generating incomplete data or files in blank -no records, just headers-.

Looking around we find out that when we use `BETWEEN CLAUSE` like this:

```
SELECT id, name, lastname FROM employee WHERE date_start BETWEEN :P_INIT_DATE AND :P_FINAL DATE
```

The resulting file was in blank or with records with mismatched dates, so we deduced there were a problem between Windows 7 date understanding and the Oracle database or whatever, we don't know yet. We could solve all this doing a double conversion `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(:P_DATE))` but now, when we want to generare a CSV file with forms 10g using `CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE`, we're experimenting a strange behavior. Webutil starts writting a file, but when this reaches certain number of lines it overwrites the same file starting in the beginnig of the CSV file again. So when you open the file in excel you only see the X last lines.

I would really apprecieate any help to fix this problems. There is no specific question, I just explain the problem we have, looking for help

Comment: Don't know - but this might help: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=566110

Answer (score 0):

CLIENT_TEXT_IO caches records before writing them to your file.  I've seen several different thresholds in the range you cite.  If your Form code issues a SYNCHRONIZE; every so many records written, the cache will be flushed each SYNCHRONIZE.  I'm not writing large files at the moment, but in the past 100 records per SYNCHRONIZE has worked well.  Check your timings carefully; 100 may be too few records per SYNCHRONIZE.  Since the number I've seen varies from shop to shop, I'd wager it's NOT related solely to number of records, but how many bytes you stuff into your cache.